# JMeter - How can you see/manipulate a Thread Group's - 'Thread Properties' values

Tags: jmeter

I am developing a Test Harness, for which some on here have assisted, so great thanks to you all.

But as part of my Test Harness journey (and stupidity along it) I wanted to know what exactly was being sent when a Thread Group is started, specifically, the ThreadGroup's 'Thread Properties' values for the:

- Loop Count: Infinite checkbox
- Specify Thread lifetime checkbox

Is it possible to get and manipulate the values of the fields via say JSR223 or Beanshell elements as I would like to manipulate them at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

As of [JMeter 5.5](https://lists.apache.org/thread/k575c2oqnr0pv52fckcg399o4nkqt8c6) there is no possibility to change these parameters in the runtime

The options are in:

1. Use [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) to pass the values from file or command-line arguments when you start the test
2. Basically the same as point 1 but if you need i.e. more complex calculations you can amend the properties somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) using suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) ([using Beanshell is not generally recommended](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting))

It's also possible to set the "Loop Count" to "Infinite" and "Thread lifetime" to something very big and stop the test using JSR223 Test Element or [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler if it helps